# How do you handle an unknown number of command line arguments?

Tags: c, networking, command

I'm making a type of Node client that takes as parameters:

```
./node <port> <address> <neighbourAddress>:<weight>
```

I have handled both port and address, and stored their values in each of their own variables through atoi. However, I don't know how to handle

```
<neighbourAddress>:<weight>
```

as they can appear repeatedly. E.g.

```
./node 8888 1 26:2 34:3 12:8
```

In this case, it appears three times, but is not limited only to that amount. 
What do I have to do in order to read the arguments separated by ':' and store their values in a variable?

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "print_lib.h"

int port;
int ownAddress;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    if(argc >= 3){

        /* to receive port number */
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
        if((port <= 1024 || port >= 65535) && port != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Port number has to be between 1024 and 65535.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* to receive ownaddress */
        ownAddress = atoi(argv[2]);
        if(ownAddress >= 1024 && ownAddress != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Node's address has to be less than 1024.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* below here is where I need to handle reoccuring arguments */
        /* in the format <neighbourAddress>:<weight> */

    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too few arguments\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to *access* the arguments or how to *store* them?  Or both?

Comment: But the numver of arguments is not "_unknown_", merely variable, and the number is indicated by `argc`.  It is not clear what problem you have here, because it is clearly not an issue of an unknown number of arguments.  Perhaps you have a problem with _iteration_, but that is pretty fundamental to any coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop in combination with `sscanf`:

```
for (int i = 3; i < argc; i++) {
    int addr, weight;
    if (sscanf(argv[i], "%d:%d", &addr, &weight) != 2) ERROR();
    // use values here, e.g. assign them into an array.
}
```

Comment: @novicekiddo5131 If this solved your problem don’t forget to mark the answer as “accepted” by clicking on the big check mark on its left.

Answer (score 1):

Use `argc` to get the number of input parameters, subtract: program name, port, address and you are left with the number of `<neighbourAddress>:<weight>` inputs, you can then just loop through them. ie number of `<neighbourAddress>:<weight>` is `argc - 3`